# Making dynamic wellPanels in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I've been searching and trying to make wellPanels in Shiny dynamic but with no joy. By dynamic I mean they should only apear when the objects that they will contain are created and not before.

Below is some reproduceble code to ilustrate the problem. You will see that even before any plot is shown the wellPanel and the caption are displayed. The caption here is simply a helpText and I can make this reactive but not the wellPanel. To be honest this does not affect the functionality of the app but it is just not pretty and is driving me nuts.

```
library(shiny)

ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My example shiny"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, wellPanel(
      numericInput("n", "N:", min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),
       actionButton("goButton", "Go!")  

    )),

    column(6,

           wellPanel(
           plotOutput("plot1", width = 400, height = 300),
           helpText("Caption: This text should appear at the same time as the plot and well"),
           #verbatimTextOutput("text")
           )
    )
  )
)
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  plot1 <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
     hist(rnorm(input$n))   

    })


   output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
     plot1()

      })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The app will have multiple wellPanels and it would be nice not to have the initial display full of empty panels has it gives the impression that something is not right.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you using `conditionalPanel`?

```
library(shiny)

ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My example shiny"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, wellPanel(
      numericInput("n", "N:", min = 0, max = 100, value = 50),
      actionButton("goButton", "Go!")  
    )),
    column(6,
           conditionalPanel("output.hide_panel",
              wellPanel(
                plotOutput("plot1", width = 400, height = 300),
                helpText("Caption: This text should appear at the same time as the plot and well")
              )
           )
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$hide_panel <- eventReactive(input$goButton, TRUE, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  outputOptions(output, "hide_panel", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

  plot1 <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    hist(rnorm(input$n))   
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot1()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for help, it does the job perfectly. I haven’t came across the conditionalPanel before and I'm surprised that it did not show in my web search. Once again thank you. Cheers